# Twilio client connecting to Conference ignores beep parameter plays entry/exit tones

Tags: javascript, twilio

Given the following Twiml snippet, when my javascript client running on Chrome 31 dials into a conference it still receives entry/exit tones despite `beep="false"` and `waitUrl=""`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial timeLimit="5400" callerId="client:myuser2">
     <Conference startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="false" muted="false" maxParticipants="7" beep="false" waitUrl="" > myuser2 </Conference>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Twilio employee here.

Comment: I copied your code into a simple Twilio Client application to see if I could replicate your issue, but I could not. Setting beep to false indeed turned the beep off when entering a conference call. However, there are sounds that play when a the Twilio Client JS SDK initializes incoming or outgoing calls. YOu can turn these sounds off by setting the proper flags to false, more info here (scroll down to Sounds Reference): https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device